# Role based routing issue on laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following 2 routes in the `web.php` of my laravel application.

```
Route::get('/admins', 'Admin\DashboardController@index')->middleware('role:1');
Route::get('/admins', 'Admin\DashboardController@index')->middleware('role:2');
```

But the first route is not functioning properly since it's sending the users with role id 1 to a different route instead of the admin dashboard, which is home.

How can I send the bote users to the same route?

I have the following function in my login controller

```
public function redirectTo() {
        $role = Auth::user()->role_id; 
        switch ($role) {
          
          case '1':
            case '2':
            return '/admins';
            break;
          
            case '3':
            return '/users/profile';
            break;   
      
          default:
            return '/home'; 
          break;
        }
      }
```

Comment: whats the role id? and where is the user being redirected to right now?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware#middleware-parameters

Comment: Why don't you put **return and break** after case '1' ?

Comment: @sid the users who have role id 2 (regional admins) is redirecting to the admin dashboard but the super admins who have user id is 1 directing to home, not the dashboard...

Answer (score 0):

```
protected $redirectTo = '/home'; //Default path to redirect

public function redirectTo() {
    $role = Auth::user()->role_id;
    if($role == 1 || $role == 2){ // Check if admin or reginal admin
        $this->redirectTo = '/admins';
    }
    elseif($role == 3) { // noraml user
        $this->redirectTo = '/users/profile';
    }
    return $this->redirectTo;
}
```

Remove one route of `/admins` from `web.php` and Remove middleware check or don't pass role id. because maybe you are rechecking in middleware for user role.
You don't have to pass role id.
You can get `Auth::user()->role_id` in middleware.

Comment: Hey, this has worked, but if a normal user logged (user id is 3) in and tried to access the admin dashboard URL it gives a controller error without redirecting to the home page...

Comment: First of all, why a normal user accessing admins' URL?
if some method you have created in the same controller as admins which is not good. I prefer to create a separate controller for normal users.
What error you are getting?